# Retun x character AFTER a string SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to return the following 4 characters after a string in a column 'E.Notes'

Example string '**Code:** ABCD'

Target output 'ABCD'

I've tried to no avail ;-(

```
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('<strong>Code:</strong> ', E.Notes) > 0 THEN
LEFT(E.Notes, CHARINDEX('<strong>Code:</strong> ', E.Notes) 4) 
ELSE '' END
```

Comment: is that 'Code:' is fixed in your string??

Answer (score 0):

USE `SUBSTRING()` OR `RIGHT()` SHOULD BE OK.

```
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('<strong>Code:</strong> ', E.Notes) > 0 THEN
SUBSTRING(E.Notes, CHARINDEX('<strong>Code:</strong> ', E.Notes) + LEN('<strong>Code:</strong> '), 255) 
ELSE '' END

CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('<strong>Code:</strong> ', E.Notes) > 0 THEN
RIGHT(E.Notes,LEN( E.Notes) + 1 - LEN('<strong>Code:</strong>') - CHARINDEX('<strong>Code:</strong> ', E.Notes) ) 
ELSE '' END
```

AND YOU CAN USE `RTRIM()`  OR `LTRIM()` TO GET RID OF SPACES.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Notes VARCHAR(200) = '<strong>Code:</strong> ABCDkkkk'

SELECT CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('Code:', @Notes) > 0
            THEN RIGHT(@Notes, LEN(@Notes) - CHARINDEX('Code:', @Notes) - 14)
        ELSE ''
        END
```

**EDITED**

By OP's demand to get only first 4 character from the string.

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('Code:', @Notes) > 0
            THEN LEFT(RIGHT(@Notes, LEN(@Notes) - CHARINDEX('Code:', @Notes) - 14), 4)
        ELSE ''
        END
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it's not the next 4, but all characters after the string.

Comment: @Mike: But you have not mentioned it. Anyways i have modify my answer. Please check it.